# Failure to copy domains ARC copy file geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, arcgis-10.5, domains, windows-10

I am  using ARC copy file geodatabase to convert my current file database to an earlier version. I have made all features visible in the table of contents and when I invoke the tool the  table of contents flash and it creates a named gdb in the correct location but it does not copy any domains. All domains are within my current gdb. I have checked file and folder access and they are all read / write and have done a simple feature copy and that works.

Comment: What versions are you copying from and copying as?

Comment: Copy in ArcCatalog, ArcMap will only copy the features. You can use the tool Create File Geodatabase http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000pw000000 to create a database to a previous version then copy the feature classes and feature datasets into the new geodatabase; the version of the database will not change unless you upgrade to the current version.

Comment: I m copying from 10.5 to 10.3 .... thanks for your reply I misunderstood the create file functionality. I assume that any features which are not supported in 10.0 will be deleted / ignored ?

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @MichaelStimson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254252/failure-to-copy-domains-arc-copy-file-geodatabase/254269#comment400765_254252):

> Copy in ArcCatalog, ArcMap will only copy the features. You can use
>   the tool Create File Geodatabase
>   http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000pw000000
>   to create a database to a previous version then copy the feature
>   classes and feature datasets into the new geodatabase; the version of
>   the database will not change unless you upgrade to the current
>   version.